# Copying data (merge) between tables from different databases without a dblink (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

What is the best way to insert or update data from one table to another(same structure) without a dblink.

Here is how I do it with a dblink:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_1 loc
USING (
  SELECT ID, CODE, NAME
  FROM TABLE_1@db_link) rem
ON (loc.ID = rem.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET loc.CODE = rem.CODE, loc.NAME=rem.NAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (loc.ID, loc.CODE, loc.NAME)
  VALUES (rem.ID, rem.CODE, rem.NAME);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DB link suggests that the 2 schemas are on 2 different databases. that means there is no direct link between the 2 data stores

in such a scenario, the following are your options(that i know of):

Option 1: create a synonym for the DB link and use that synonym for the same in ur sql. that way when u update the db link..u just need to update the synonym and not the sql itself..

Option 2: create a stage schema where the data will be pushed from the source db via web service or data upload(flat file) or some other means. then use the same sql but referrencing a synonym of the stage schema

other than this i dont think there are options.

[Forum](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?27310-database-links-alternative)

Comment: As proposed in the link you put, I used Java to get the data and then inserted from one table, and then inserted in the other, the performance is not the best but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could generate merge statements for each record in one DB, save produced script and run it on another DB. Please, be aware of null values

```
SELECT '
  merge into table_1 loc
  using ( select ' || nvl(to_char(id), 'null') || ' id, ' || '''' || code || '''' || ' code, ''' || name || ''' name from dual ) rem ' ||
 'ON (loc.ID = rem.ID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET loc.CODE = rem.CODE, loc.NAME=rem.NAME
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (loc.ID, loc.CODE, loc.NAME) VALUES (rem.ID, rem.CODE, rem.NAME);' stmt
FROM TABLE_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting the records and then on target database side just create an external table referencing this file.